# How to make this code better?

Tags: java

I wrote some code like this in Java:

```
    //...
    if(dsLen>=4){
        ds.longitude = buff.readInt();
        dsLen-=4;
    }
    else{
        return ds;
    }

    if(dsLen>=4){
        ds.latitude = buff.readInt();
        dsLen-=4;
    }
    else{
        return ds;
    }

    if(dsLen>=2){
        ds.velocity = buff.readShort();
        dsLen-=2;
    }
    else{
        return ds;
    }
    //...
```

It seems ugly. How can I improved it?

As far as I know, Java does not support reference value via arguments. That's really a puzzle to me.

Comment: What's the code *before* that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a class like this:

```
class MaybeReader {
  BufferType buff;
  int dsLen;
  boolean failed = false;

  // Add a constructor to populate buff and dsLen appropriately.

  boolean failed(long obj) {
    return failed;
  }

  int maybeReadInt(int defaultValue) {
    if (dsLen >= 4) {
      dsLen -= 4;
      return buff.readInt();
    } else {
      failed = true;
      return defaultValue;
    }
  }

  short maybeReadShort(short defaultValue) {
    if (dsLen >= 2) {
      dsLen -= 2;
      return buff.readShort();
    } else {
      failed = true;
      return defaultValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can invoke it reasonably compactly like this:

```
MaybeReader m = new MaybeReader(...);
if (m.failed(ds.longitude = m.maybeReadInt(ds.longitude))
    || m.failed(ds.latitude = m.maybeReadInt(ds.latitude))
    || m.failed(ds.velocity = m.maybeReadShort(ds.velocity)) {
  return ds;
}
```

This works as follows:

- You need to pass in the current value of the field, in order that you can write it back in the case that you can't read the value from the buffer.
- The `maybeRead*` methods will read from the buffer if there is enough data; otherwise, they return the default value, and set the instance into a "failed" state.
- The result of the `maybeRead*` is then passed back into `failed`. The argument isn't actually used, it is just to use the assignment as an boolean expression rather than a statement. This involves a widening cast to `long`; you can add overloads for specific primitive types, if you want.
- The fast-break evaluation of the `||` means that execution will stop as soon as one of the `maybeRead*` calls fail.

**However**: I don't think that this is especially intuitive to read, however; in particular, expressions with multiple side effects (the assignments) are considered hard to read. I would just accept that Java can be a verbose language, and write code that is obvious at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `dsLen` is irrelevant after a return statement was executed, your code can be simplified as

```
    if (dsLen >= 4) {
        ds.longitude = buff.readInt();
    }

    if (dsLen >= 8) {
        ds.latitude = buff.readInt();
    }

    if (dsLen >= 10) {
        ds.velocity = buff.readShort();
    }

    return ds;
```

The rest of the code could be improved as well.  It looks like `longitude`, `latitute` and `velocity` are `public` fields of `ds`.  It's probably a better idea to encapsulate them by making them `private` instead.

If you really need to change the state of `ds` in other parts of the code, use a setter.

If you don't need to change the state of `ds`, consider making the fields `final`, assign them in the constructor and return a new object of ds' type in the method in your question,

```
public final class WhateverType {

    private final int longitude;
    private final int latitude;
    private final short velocity;

    public WhateverType(int longitude, int latitude, short velocity) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    // rest of the code
}
```

then the code in your method could look like:

```
    int longitude = -1;  // or whatever default values you're assigning
    int latitude = -1;
    short velocity = -1;

    if (dsLen >= 4) {
        longitude = buff.readInt();
    }

    if (dsLen >= 8) {
        latitude = buff.readInt();
    }

    if (dsLen >= 10) {
        velocity = buff.readShort();
    }

    return new WhateverType(longitude, latitude, velocity);
```